# I have disabled Enter key by following code is it possible to undo that effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

code to disable Enter

```
$('#frmLogin').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

I have disabled enter key in above code now if i want to undo that effect on another event,is it possible.Please help .thnaks in advance

Comment: You could just unbind specific event or use some flag inside handler. **EDIT:** What do you mean by `i want to undo that effect on another event`? You'd really have better to provide a concrete example of what you are looking for...

Comment: Undo on another event? If it is another event, that code is not in there so it should just work?

Comment: now i have prevented enter key press event.after some activities i want to enable enter key press event

Answer (score 1):

Check out [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#frmLogin').unbind("keypress");
});
```